# Can not get value inside loop using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why I cannot get value inside the loop
Can use javascript only

Pause text for 2000ms on hover 
reverse work on hover but should pause it first and then reverse the sequence until mouse out.

loop on reading text from textarea "input"

find this line in javascript to control delay

if(document.getElementById('flag2').value == "0"){

```js
/*
      1 : center
 2 -  4 : center 2
 5 -  7 : center 3
 8 - 10 : center 4
11 - 13 : center 5
14 - 16 : center 6
17 - 19 : center 7
*/

stopNow= false;
function Loop(txt, wpm) {
    txt = txt.replace(/\n/g, ' ');
    var a = txt.split(' '),
        n = a.length,
        i = 0,
        b = document.getElementById('bw'),
        tw = document.getElementById('tw'),
        tx = {
            L: document.getElementById('txt_L'),
            C: document.getElementById('txt_C'),
            R: document.getElementById('txt_R')
        }
    ;
    function width(w) {
        tw.textContent = w;
        return tw.offsetWidth;
    }
    function middle(w) {
    var x = 0;
        var n = w.length,
            // Center char calculation. 1=1, 2-4=2, 5-7=3, ...
            c = ~~((n + 1) / 3) + 1,
            z = {};
       if (!n)
            return;
        z.a = width(w.substr(0, c - 1));
        z.b = width(w.substr(0, c));
        z.c = (z.b - z.a) / 2;
        b.style.paddingLeft = ~~(110 - (z.a + z.c)) + 'px';

        tx.L.textContent = w.substr(0, c - 1);
        tx.C.textContent = w.substr(c - 1, 1);
        tx.R.textContent = w.substr(c);
    }
    function word() {
        if(stopNow){
            middle(a[i])
            if (--i === n)
                i = 0;
                return 0;
                }
                else{
                 middle(a[i])
            if (++i === n)
                i = 0;
                return 0;
                }
    }
    this.whiteout = function(w) {
        if (w) {
            tx.L.style.color = '#fff';
            tx.R.style.color = '#fff';
        } else {
            tx.L.style.color = '#080';
            tx.R.style.color = '#000';            
        }
    };
    wpm = wpm || 200;
    var __time = 2000;
    //can not get changes value here 
    if(document.getElementById('flag2').value == "0"){
    __time = (60/wpm) * 1000;}
    document.getElementById('flag1').innerHTML += document.getElementById('flag2').innerHTML ;
    var tt = setInterval(function (){
    document.getElementById('flag1').innerHTML = word();
    }, __time); 
}

var txt = document.getElementById('input').value;
var ww = new Loop(txt, 250);
document.getElementById('bw').addEventListener('change', function() {
    ww.whiteout(this.checked);
});
document.getElementById('txtHolder').addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
    stopNow = true;
    document.getElementById('flag2').innerHTML = "1";
});
document.getElementById('txtHolder').addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
    stopNow = false;
    document.getElementById('flag2').innerHTML = "0";
});
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
#tw { 
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap; 
    
}
#tw,
#txt_L,
#txt_C,
#txt_R
{
    font: bold 18px Arial;
    line-height: 1;
}
#txt_L { color: #000; }
#txt_C { color: #f00; }
#txt_R { color: #000; }
#wrap {
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
#b1 {
    width: 110px;
    height: 50px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    float:left;
}
#bw {
    position: absolute;
    width: 220px;
    top: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px 0;
    line-height: 1;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!--
EXTRA POINTS---------
Pause text for 2000ms on hover and reverse the sequence until mouse out.
-->

<div id="flag1">

</div>
<div id="flag2">

</div>

<div id="txtHolder">
<span id="tw"></span>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="b1"></div>
    <div id="bw"><span id="txt_L">&nbsp;</span><span id="txt_C"></span><span id="txt_R"></span></div>
</div>

</div>

<textarea id="input" class="hide">
Oh, hey there, TIDWRTWHUFOO fans. Thinking about going for a little dip this summer? How about you go for a swim with a one-ton crab that will smash you under its massive legs? Sound fun? Definitely!

Crabster is a wild crab-like robot designed to explore the deepest oceans without smashing itself into a squashed tin can. It has massive legs, a large body, and lots of cameras so it can find you even if you’re the dude from The Big Blue and can dive really deep. There’s no escaping our future robotic-aquatic overlords
</textarea>
```

Comment: please more clarify what you want to do....its still unclear without explanation but code.

Comment: i  want to Pause text for 2000ms on hover and reverse the sequence until mouse out.

Comment: reverse working on hover but i need to make pause it for 2000ms

Comment: Find this 
//can not get changes value here 
    if(document.getElementById('flag2').value == "0"){

Comment: Can you explain how your code is suppose to work? Seems like you have a simple problem but I'm having a hard time figuring out what's your intention.

Comment: That what am facing

Comment: It should keep reading from hidden textarea and there are a box should read from textarea and display single word at atime, on hover should pause it 2 seconds and reverse display words, process will stay until mouse hover outside the box